# view with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

How to map a view with multiple entiites using Hibernate?

Regards,
chaitu

Answer (score 8):

See the section 5.1.3 "Class", in the Hibernate documentation, right before the section "Id":

> There is no difference between a view and a base table for a Hibernate mapping. This is transparent at the database level, although some DBMS do not support views properly, especially with updates. Sometimes you want to use a view, but you cannot create one in the database (i.e. with a legacy schema).

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class

There's also an example on how to do that using XML.

Answer (score 6):

Subselect is your natural choice.Here is a working example: Say we have a view named "view1" in the DBMS. You don't need anything else, althought if the view is not updatable, using @Immutable would be nice for performance issues. Notice that you must have an id column in your class and in the view

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select * from view1")
public class EventView {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Please see my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269722/hibernate-view-creation-wont-work

Answer (score 4):

you can use a @subselect annotation

here are an example of official documentation:

```
@Entity
@Subselect("select item.name, max(bid.amount), count(*) "
    + "from item "
    + "join bid on bid.item_id = item.id "
    + "group by item.name")
@Synchronize( {"item", "bid"} ) //tables impacted
public class Summary {
    @Id
    public String getId() { return id; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Please see my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269722/hibernate-view-creation-wont-work