# hibernate from view

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, view, hql

I'm trying to create a hibernate mapping from a view of multiple tables
viewname: calls

I'm using Java annotations in Netbeans

when I auto generate the POJ from the database i get2 classes
one is the same name as the view: calls and the other is callsid

now when I test the HQL query: from Calls
Netbeans runs the query but stops executing at 80%

anyone had this problem before
any takes on how to solve this?

any help would greatly be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Don't create your entity of the view the wrong way.If you use @SqlResultSetMapping and @NamedNativeQuery to create a view, your code will work fine and use the view correctly but hibernate auto ddl feature will create an unused table for your entity.You can see the most straight way to create a view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111176/view-with-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate needs an id to map an entity. What are the contents of callsid ?
Maybe this would help [mapping-hibernate-entities-to-views](http://timezra.blogspot.com/2009/05/mapping-hibernate-entities-to-views.html). In the "views" section there's example code to map an entity to a view.