# Create SQL view with panache

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm using

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
     <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and I would like to generate an SQL view in the same way we generate tables, specifically as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Invoice extends PanacheEntityBase {
...
}
```

I've tried that way but with no really success, I can't found anything on this in quarkus' documentation:

```
@Entity
@Subselect("SELECT i.id as invoiceId, i.appointmentIds FROM invoice i")
public class BilledAppointments extends PanacheEntityBase {
    @Column
    public Long invoiceId;

    @Column
    public String appointmentsIds;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that views are not managed by frameworks but only by databases. So it is not really possible to map a view to a "classic" entity, since Panache will interprate this as a table and create one. Moreover, if you create a view manually in your database that references one of your entities, it may be deleted if you adopt the drop-and-create strategy.

A solution is:

```
@Entity
public class MyTable extends PanacheEntityBase {}
```

```
@Entity
@Subselect("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
@Synchronize("MyTable")
public class MyView extends PanacheEntityBase {}
```

- [Helful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111176/view-with-hibernate)
- [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class)